# Should all public API POCO value-type properties be nullables?

Tags: design, .net, api, null

I use nullable value types a lot when designing classes that have properties which may remain null, i.e. when the object is being persisted.  For example:

```
public int? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

My question is: should all value-type properties in public (API) POCOs be nullable because it's not known when the consumer will set the values, even in cases where the properties *must not* be null when the POCO is saved?  If not, then there's the risk that the "default" value (e.g. `0` for an `int`) will accidentally be saved.

Comment: 0 isn't null.  If you can't persist a null as a null, then why use nullables in the first place?

Comment: I know 0 isn't null.  The point is the consumer must supply a non-null value before persisting.  If the value-type property isn't provided by the consumer when they're filling the POCO, then it will be, e.g. 0 (for `int`).  That's ambiguous because it may be a valid value.

Comment: It's possible to serialize a nullable and keep the null value.  See [Serialize a nullable int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/244953/427192)

Comment: I'm not trying to serialize anything.  I'm persisting the data in a database.

Comment: That's even better - your field in the database just has to permit NULL values.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point - you know how to store NULLs, but your business rules prevent you from doing so?

Comment: To better understand, are you wanting to accept NULL values into your api and then throw a null ref exception at some point before you save the data or save nulls to the database if the client does not provide a value?

Comment: I know how to store NULLs, yes, and yes the business rules indicate that these values can't be null.  I don't know when the consumer will set the values, if ever, before they are validated and then persisted.

Comment: @WindRaven -- The former.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make the setters private and use a constructor? That way that kind of validation can be done there, and by the time the object is populated, you'll already have guarantees about the data. Not sure how you're doing your database communication, but ORMs should support private setters

Comment: @BenAaronson -- I'm not sure.  Is that better?  It seems like an alternative approach, yes, but maybe there's a good reason to perform the validation all at once.  Efficiency perhaps.  What if the consumer attempts to set the value multiple times -- that's a lot of validation when it need only be done once, right before the save.

Comment: @roryap Not sure what you mean. The validation would only be done once, on construction. It's more complex if your objects need to be mutable, but still doable. Even if you just keep your setters public, you'd at the very least have the guarantee that some initial value had been set for your `int` field, the caller couldn't just forget to do that.

Comment: @BenAaronson -- My bad; yes, the objects need to be mutable and I don't like bloated constructors.  I'm still not sure how that approach is better than using nullable properties, though.

Comment: @BenAaronson: Objects doing their own validation is complicated by things like the need to display multiple validation errors on a web page.  You need infrastructure for that.  In the early days of ASP.NET MVC, this was done by having an IsValid method in the business object, and a ValidationErrors collection.  Nowadays, domain object fields are decorated with validation attributes.  Then there's ViewModel objects...

Comment: "Persistence" and "serialization" are the same thing. The answer to your question, as written in the title, is "no". I would rewrite the title to indicate this question is specific to one type of serialization framework.